# Modal PopUp Appears without real error

Tags: magento-2.1.8, modal-popup

I'm using the Bitnami Magento Virtual Machine.

Virtual Machine. `Debian 8 ( with mariadb, php 7.0, apache2 , memcached && more )`

The documentation:
https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/magento/

I explain the problem:

[image: popup triggered]

The popup window is triggered without actually occurring an error as far as I can see in the logs, they are only notifications.

I attach only Pages but is the same for the customers, etc..

the system.log file:

> [2017-08-31 09:55:25] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles
>   catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  []
>   []

and more ..

the debug.log file:

> [2017-08-31 09:36:51] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"192.168.1.136/admin/admin/index/index/key/1e497d0840c72302fd6a8e103fef7da02440f1fb8fd10260bf56405ff112fe6b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false}
>   []

I read posts where I had to use varnish to fix it, others I had to modify the `ui_bookmark` table and remove the title with null which I accessed at that time, but nothing.

Could you give me an option to disable all these popups from the admin panel or else a code fix to fix the problem?

Anything else that is missing please tell me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by leaving the index.php as it was without adding extra code to be able to see all the errors of the system

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("");
    print_r($error);
}

and at the same time I have re-executed the command :

sudo chmod -R 0777 ./var

I know it will be a rookie mistake, but I hope this helps someone.